# PHP OO Call to a non-object

Tags: php

I have recently started coding in php again and am learning Object Orientated PHP.
I have come across an issue that I cannot seem to get my head round with an error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function verify_Username_And_Password() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\sso\lib\UserManagement.php on line 57

I understand that the program seems to think that the mysql class variable is empty but not why when it is instanced.

The function verify_Username_And_Password ($username, $password) is defined in the class Mysql.

The following is code from UserManagement.php with parts taken out that are not needed.

```
<?PHP
require_once 'lib/Mysql.php';

class UserManagement {
    private $mysql;

    function __construct(){
        session_start();
        $this->manage_Session();
        $this->mysql = new Mysql();
    }

    function validate_User ($username, $password){
        $user_Check = $this->mysql->verify_Username_And_Password($username, md5($password));

        if($user_Check) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I must be missing something basic about OO in PHP. I would be grateful for any advice anyone can give. I will be happy to post more code if needed.

As requested here is:
Mysql.php [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/J2p9Qphu).
UserManagement.php [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/iuFnjfQC)

Comment: Can you show us the Mysql.php code

Comment: Can you post the code that constructs the UserManagement object and calls `validate_User()`?

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong there, but it implies `$this->mysql` hasn't been set - or maybe it got set and then overwritten by code elsewhere in your class. What's in the `Mysql.php` file? Is there anywhere else that `$this->mysql` gets overwritten?

Comment: Do you not have a separate script that does something like: `$um = new userManagement(); $um->validate_User($user, $pw);` ?

Comment: I think this is all about debugging. Check if after `$this->mysql = new Mysql();` there is object. If so - examine what is done between constructor and validate_User, because something could overwrite variable. Anyways, this would be much more productive than our guessings here.

Comment: I have added the other code via pastebin that was requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the code that does the work, my guess would be you are using the validate_User method without first constructing a UserMangement object.

```
$um = new UserManagement();
$um->validate_User($username, $password);
```

If you wish to call validate_User without first constructing a UserManagement object it needs to be a [static method](http://phpduck.com/php-static-methods-and-properties/). Without the UserManagement object being constructed Mysql is never constructed and saved in the attribute inside your class.

Comment: The user management class was constructed but thinking about what you said and going through the UserManagement class again. manage_Session uses validate_User and the variable was empty because it was trying to create it after calling manage_Session(). A few hours of pulling out my hair for placing a line of code in the wrong place. Thanks you very much for your help guys sorry it was such a silly mistake.